# Can the causative verb "help" be used in a passive sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Can the causative verb "help" be used in a passive sentence? For example, does the sentence

> I was helped by him to carry the boxes.

make sense to you, native speakers?

Answer (score 1):

It's a valid sentence, but it is still passive voice and so sounds rather clunky. I'd rewrite it as:

> He helped me to carry the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

One might hear the passive used in that way in a courtroom setting, but in normal contexts active voice would be used:

**District Attorney: Did anyone help you throw the dead body into the river?

Witness:  I was helped by *him* [witness points at the defendant]**